# I'm trying to preprocess a dataset for mimic2 but I'm officially stuck. Newbie alert

Tags: python

I'd like to preface by saying I am WAY in over my head working with datasets, machine learning, AI ,etc. Anyways..

Just downloaded some data sets from LJSpeech and I ran `python3 preprocess.py --dataset ljspeech` and I received this jumble

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocess.py", line 5, in <module>
    from datasets import preprocessor
  File "/home/boofygirl/mycroft-core/Tacotron-2/datasets/preprocessor.py", line 6, in <module>
    from datasets import audio
  File "/home/boofygirl/mycroft-core/Tacotron-2/datasets/audio.py", line 1, in <module>
    import librosa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    from .time_frequency import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/librosa/core/time_frequency.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/librosa/util/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from .utils import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/librosa/util/utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .decorators import deprecated
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numba.decorators import jit as optional_jit
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numba.decorators'
```

I inadvertently stayed up past my bedtime by 5 hours so my brain is officially fried. Will I have to go into preprocess.py? I think I reached my limit on mycroft until I've learned more of the basics of python but I'd love some suggestions.

Comment: Looks like an issue with the numba module. You can try this in the command line ```pip install numba==0.48```. Found this solution [here](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1160)

Comment: The Problem is Data Science is not programming and vise versa. 
I do agree with @Wavy Based on the error message. You should give `pip install numba==x.x` a try. In case it does not help you need to provide more detail.

Comment: So like a fool that fixed that issue. However when I attempt to run `python3 preprocess.py --dataset ljspeech` simply returns _Illegal Instruction (core dumped). I'm not receiving an error `boofygirl@Caretaker:~/mycroft-core/Tacotron-2$ python3 preprocess.py --dataset LJSpeech
Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `numba` rearranged their code so what was `numba.decorators` is now `numba.core.decorators` (with version .50 ?)

The best solution is the one in the comments, i.e. install an older version, e.g.:

```
pip install numba==0.48
```

Another option (by definition, not the *best* option :-) is to modify the file in librosa that does the import, which is the last one listed in the error message, `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py`

```
# need change for subrosa, numba rearranged things :-/
try:
    from numba.decorators import jit as optional_jit
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from numba.core.decorators import jit as optional_jit
```

But it's best not to mess with that unless you know what you're doing, especially in /usr/local/lib.  A third option would be to create a virtual environment, install everything you need and make the change there, then you aren't messing with any system installed files.

And if any of this is confusing (i.e. how to create a virtual env, or how to edit a file with root permissions &c) then go with option 1.  You'll thank me later :-)